# Big-O notation of 1+2+3+...+n

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I'm currently a CS undergrad enrolled in a data structures course.  During the semester, we learned about big-O notation, and on one assignment, we had to write out the big-O notation of summing the numbers 1+2+3+...+n.  I figured that, in the simplest method, you would be be looping from 1 to n and in each iteration adding i to the sum, so it seemed like this would be O(n) time.

I am also aware that this specific summation can be expressed as (n(n+1))/2 as a more direct way to receive the answer.

My professor insists that in both cases, the time complexity is O(n^2), and I have been emailing him back and forth hoping to get a better explanation, but he basically sends the same reply every time.

I feel like I must be misunderstanding the purpose of big-O in the first place.  Even when I implement these 2 methods of finding the sum in a program and time the execution, the time of the loop method seems to increase linearly based on the size of n, and in the second method, it takes the same amount of time no matter how large n is because there is no iteration occurring in this case.

Could someone please help me understand why this would still be O(n^2)?

Comment: It's coming from him telling me that the answer depends on the number of operations we are performing, and in the case of (n(n+1)/2, I only see 3 operations happening there.  If he would take the time to properly explain it instead of sending me "the answer is O(n^2) because it is (n(n+1))/2" as a reply no matter how many times I ask him to explain.

Answer (score 2):

You are computing the order of the wrong value.

As you indicated in a comment, the question does not ask what's the time complexity of *doing* the sum; the question asks what is the order of the *sum itself*. And indeed 1 + 
2 + ... + n is O(n²).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in a response to one of my emails when I had asked if we were only concerned with the order and not time complexity, he said that this problem had to do with time complexity and the number of operations being performed.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. 1+...+n = O(n²). The problem has nothing to do with the computation time of the sum.

Answer (score 1):

In a Java example like this

```
int n = 1000;
int sum = 0;

// iterating n times
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    // just a basic operation, so no extra complexity here
    sum += i;
}
```

the addition is called `n` times, so the whole code has a time complexity of **O(1) * n = O(n)**.

If there is nothing missing in your question, **O(n)** will be the correct answer to the task.

Anyway, there is a good chance the professor is right ;-)

**O(n * (n + 1) / 2) = O(n / 2) * O((n + 1) / 2) = O(n) * O(n + 1) = O(n) * O(n) = O(n * n) = O(n^2)**

Comment: I really don't know what to think now, his latest reply to me was "each iteration requires i operations, so all together we have n(n+1)/2 operations" and I am just getting more confused because in the case of that formula, there is no iteration occurring afaik?

Comment: It would be nice to know what happens in each iteration (the professor is thinking of)... I hope he does not mean `n` iterations of summing up values from `1` to `n`...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, and getting any reply out of him other than that the answer is O(n^2) is seeming pretty unlikely

Comment: Giving you the right answer without an explanation is a really weird way to teach... Then give the right answer, pass the assignment and discuss with others. I think there is no different option apart from talking to different professors, maybe.

Comment: summing input using formula (n * (n + 1))/2 complexity is O(1). Why do you use Big-O notation there?

Comment: I'm really not sure, it was just a multiple choice question on an assignment we had, and had I gotten it right, it would have given me an A instead of a B.  Our teacher really isn't that great.  He spends the entire class reading off someone else's powerpoints and often takes like 30 seconds to read each one himself before he starts talking.  He is never clear with his expectations for our projects, and a lot of the students clearly struggle with this class and I have heard that the Prof is of little to no help, and now I am seeing it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this is a misunderstanding and that 1, 2, ..., n are time values of another operation that is performed, meaning that the time to execute that operation constantly increases, and you have to give the Big-O for this sequence of operations?

Otherwise, when the task is really just summing up all numbers from 1 to n and express that time in Big-O-notation, your opinion is correct that it is an O(n) when you take the approach looping over all elements, and using the n*(n+1)/2-formula you get even O(1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the question taken exactly off the assignment is "Which of these is the correct big
-
O expression for 1+2+3+...+n?
A. O(log n)
B. O(n)
C. O(n log n)
D. O(n²)", so there wasn't even an option for constant time which makes it weird that he even brought up that formula in the first place.

Comment: Ok, I guess then your professor is right. I'm not a native english speaker, but the question is not to give the big-O-expression for the time needed to calculate that sum, but 1+2+...+n is the value, depending on n. And, as you correctly stated, this is n*(n+1)/2 which is (n^2)/2 + n/2, so O(n^2) is the correct answer.

Comment: That may be the case, but he keeps bringing up the number of operations occurring and iterations, but if he only means the result itself, then him bringing these things up is just making it more confusing.  I know he did not make this question himself because you can find it all over google, and he is also not a native English speaker, so this could possibly be a misunderstanding on both of our parts.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is O(n) if you do the summation by iterating over the numbers one by one.

The answer is O(1) if you use the formula for summation directly.